# Perl golf: Print the powers of a number

Tags: perl, math, code-golf

What's the shortest Perl one-liner that  print out the first 9 powers of a hard-coded 2 digit decimal (say, for example, .37), each on its own line?

The output would look something like:

```
1
0.37
0.1369
[etc.]
```

Official Perl golf rules:

1. Smallest number of (key)strokes wins
2. Your stroke count includes the command line

Comment: You don't have to play if you don't want to

Comment: Good way to get people to overcome their fear of perl as a write-only language :-P

Comment: Looks like there are two with 28 strokes, both requiring `Perl 5.10`.

Comment: @Tanktalus: Do you think perl is horrible? Look at this solution in dc: dc -e'20k1p.37dsap7[rla*pr1-d0<b]dsbx'

Comment: Does hitting shift+4 count as an extra key stroke to generate a '$'?  Your wording is potentially ambiguous.

Comment: Too easy to be a proper golf. The answer doesn't even look like line noise

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With perl 5.10.0 and above:

```
perl -E'say 0.37**$_ for 0..8'
```

With older perls you don't have `say` and -E, but this works:

```
perl -le'print 0.37**$_ for 0..8'
```

Update: the first solution is made of 30 key strokes. Removing the first 0 gives 29. Another space can be saved, so my final solution is this with 28 strokes:

```
perl -E'say.37**$_ for 0..8'
```

Comment: Dammit, that was exactly what I was going to post (though shouldn't that 9 be an 8?)

Comment: Yes, corrected. (Leon, you don't happen to frequent perlmonks as well? if yes, under which nick?)

Comment: No, I don't frequent perlmonks (though have an account there using this full name), why?

Comment: Your answers resemble those that you can find on perlmonks, so I was curios ;-)

Comment: Cut the space and 0, and you can cut 2 strokes.

Comment: I'm more a comp.lang.perl.misc user actually

Answer (score 6):

```
perl -le'map{print.37**$_}0..8'
```

31 characters - I don't have 5.10 to try out the obvious improvement using "say" but this is 28:

```
perl -E'map{say.37**$_}0..8'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
seq 9|perl -nE'say.37**$_'
```

26 - Yes, that's cheating.  (And yes, I'm doing powers from 1 to 9.  0 to 8 is just silly.)

Comment: seq 9|perl -pE'$_=.37**$_' is also 26

Comment: seq 9|perl -pe's/./.37**$_/e' not as short, but a bit obfuscated and doesn't need a new perl.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun in Perl 6:

1. 28 characters:

   ```
   perl6 -e'.say for .37»**»^9'
   ```
2. 27 characters:

   ```
   perl6 -e'say .37**$_ for^9'
   ```

(At least based on current whitespace rules.)

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -e 'print .37**$_,"\n" for 0..9'
```

If you add -l to options you can skip the ,"\n" part

Answer (score 1):

```
print join("\n", map { 0.37**$_ } (0..9));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print.37**$_.$/for 0..8
```

23 strokes if you chop the program before submitting. :-P

Comment: +9 for perl -e'..'. Remeber, "2 Your stroke count includes the command line"

Comment: I thought that was ambiguous, actually.  Tournament rules sometimes allow just the program, but add in the length of any command line switches plus a space.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -e "for(my $i = 1; $i < 10; $i++){ print((.37**$i). \"\n\"); }"
```

Just a quick entry. :)

Fixed to line break!

Comment: I think you forgot the newline - you probably need something like this:
perl -e "for(my $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){ print(.37**$i, \"\n\"); }"

Comment: Great minds think alike. Was just fixing it, but I think toolkit might just have me!

Comment: perl -e 'print .37**$_ ."\n" foreach (1..10);' # a slightly shorter version of what Abyss is doing.

Comment: If you don't want "\n", you can use $/ instead. It holds the input record separator, defaults to "\n" and is two characters shorter.