# How can I conditionally execute code in a "with" block?

Tags: python, with-statement

I guess this is kinda abusing the feature, but I'm still curious whether it could be done -
I want to do something like:

```
with conditional(a):
    print 1
```

so that the `print 1` part is executed only if a==True.
Is this possible?

EDIT:
Like people state below, this is horrible style. It's just a riddle\question. Don't try this at home, not for the faint of heart etc.

Comment: I think you'd end up with code that no-one else could ever read!  `if` is probably one of the most standar programming constructs, everyone knows it so why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: why do people play perl golf (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_golf#Perl_golf) - sometimes you just wanna see whether it can be done :)

Comment: -1: Please do not do this.  Please.

Comment: @S.Lott - I do not agree with the down vote. There's a place for everything, and so is for this kind of thing. It helps understand the language better, and is the way good programmers explore. Is this way of thinking unique to Israelis (I assume noam is, too) ?

Comment: @S.Lott - I suggest you start going over all perl golf (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_golf#Perl_golf) questions StackOverflow and downvote them:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210068/perl-golf-print-the-powers-of-a-number

Comment: @noam: I don't use perl anymore, so I don't real the perl golf questions on SO.  I use Python and Java.  I find that obscurity -- for the sake of obscurity -- to be a costly and difficult problem.  I make a fair amount of money fixing the problems that stem from clever obscurity that winds up in production software.  Feel free to continue pursuing intentionally obscure stuff.  I feel that I should be equally free to downvote it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no real reason to do that, since conditionals are already supplied using the `if` statement:

```
if a == True:
    print 1
```

But, if you're just asking for **fun**, the answer is **you can't** really. To stop the `with` content from executing, `conditional` will need to somehow stop execution, in its `__enter__` method. But the only way it can do that is raising an exception, which means no other code will run, unless you wrap the `with` with a `try` statement for handling cases `a != True`

**Edit:** seeing I was prosecuted in the comments and votes for using the OP's condition (`a == True`) I considered changing it to `if a`, which is of course the idiom in Python for testing conditionals. But, we **do not know** what the OP had in mind, and whether he really does want `a` to be a boolean, and doesn't want block to execute if `a = [1]` (which will pass `if a`) I **decided to leave it as is.**

Comment: @S.Lott: No reason to downvote the answer because it does exactly what the question requires. It is the question that says "only if `a==True`".

Comment: At least make it `a is True`.

Comment: `a is True` is *both* ugly and semantically different from `a==True` :)

Comment: Goddamit, I just copied what he said his condition should be.

Comment: How does copying it from the question make it any better? People see it and copy the code. Using `== True` is an antipattern in Python.

Comment: @Rafaek: `is True` is already much better than `== True`, and the only difference is that `is` is more efficient and better captures what you want to express.

Comment: @nikow: No, it is not the only difference. `1 == True` but `1 is not True`. Same goes for `1.0` (which is not 1.)

Comment: @Rafel: Sorry, you are right, I didn't think about that when I answered. I retracted my downvote. But while `a == True` should not be used `a is True` is legitimate (even though it is not the typical use case). Sorry again.

Answer (score 4):

```
if a is True:
    print 1
```

[`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) is intended to provide a reliable enter-exit context.

Comment: I was asking whether you can make a car can run on coca cola, and you answered "you should use fuel" :)
like i said, i know this is feature-abusing, but consider it a programming riddle - is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I see is to raise an exception in `conditional` if its argument is false. The `with` body will not be executed, but neither will any of the code that follows - until an `except` or `finally` clause, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I have class A with an __enter__ and an __exit__ function:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.b = i
    def __exit__(*args, **kwargs):
        print "exit"
    def __enter__(*args, **kwargs):
        print "enter"
```

And a function B that will check if b in object c equals 1 else it will pass.

```
def b(c):
    if c.b == 1:
        return c
    else:
        pass
```

I can achieve:

```
with b(A(1)):
    print 10


enter
10
exit
```

But it will throw an AttributeError if b passes as the *with* won't have anything to work with.
A solution would be to put the `with b(A(1)):` inside a try/except block. But I don't recommend doing this.

Comment: This doesn't work for any value other than 1 that's passed to `A`:  
    Traceback (most recent call last):  
      File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>  
        with b(A(2)):  
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__exit__'  
That's because the `pass` in `b` doesn't return a valid context manager.

Comment: sure, it throws an AttributeError if the condition fails as stated :)

Comment: You stated it fails if the arguments doesn't have a `b` attribute, but  even if it does, it will fail, if `c.b != 1`

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I do have a use case for conditional with statements. In my case,  I wanna execute some job if it is not yet done, and mark it done afterwards. Naive code:

```
if not job_done_file.exists():
   commands
   on multiple
   lines
   job_done_file.touch()
```

Problem with this is, you can easily forget the `touch()` at the end, also it’s annoying having to write `job_done_file` twice.

In C++ I could do this:

```
template <typename Function>void do_job(Function func, Path & job_done_file) {
    if (!job_done_file.exists()) {
        func();
        job_done_file.touch();
    }
}

…

do_job([]() {
    commands;
    on multiple;
    lines;
}, "/path/to/job_done_file");
```

However, in Python a lambda can only consist of one line, and it must have a return value. So instead, I would have to write a complete function to pass as a function reference, even though I might use the function only once in the entire program.

What I do instead is this:

```
@contextmanager
def do_job(job_done_file):
    yield not job_done_file.exists()
    job_done_file.touch()
…

with do_job('/path/to/job_done_file') as not_done:
    if not_done:
        commands
        on multiple
        lines
```